# How to send a single digit number to a COM port from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, serial-port, port, send

I need to send some single character commands from a batch file to a Bus Pirate hanging off a COM port, but I am having trouble sending single numbers.
If I send a double digit number it sends fine, it seems just the single digit numbers are a problem.

In the code below, the letters send fine, but the numbers don't seem to send at all.

```
Set "CNum=COM5" 
echo m>\\.\%CNum%
echo 4>\\.\%CNum%
echo 4>\\.\%CNum%
echo W>\\.\%CNum%
echo P>\\.\%CNum%
```

Is there a trick to get this working?

Comment: `for %%i in (m 4 4 W P) do (echo %%i)>\\.\%cnum%`

Comment: `echo` also appends a line-break – is that what you want?

Comment: or `set /p str="4" <nul >\\.\COM5` if you don't want a line break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you are not using the full redirection handle, so the numeric string you are sending to the COM port is being mistaken for one. i.e. `1>\\.\COM5`.

You could use either:

```
Set "CNum=COM5" 
>\\.\%CNum% echo m
>\\.\%CNum% echo 4
>\\.\%CNum% echo 4
>\\.\%CNum% echo W
>\\.\%CNum% echo P
```

or:

```
Set "CNum=COM5" 
(echo m) >\\.\%CNum%
(echo 4) >\\.\%CNum%
(echo 4) >\\.\%CNum%
(echo W) >\\.\%CNum%
(echo P) >\\.\%CNum%
```

You may even want to try:

```
Set "CNum=COM5" 
(   echo m
    echo 4
    echo 4
    echo W
    echo P
) >\\.\%CNum%
```

or:

```
Set "CNum=COM5" 
>\\.\%CNum% (
    echo m
    echo 4
    echo 4
    echo W
    echo P
)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The first option worked great.